# Xubuntu 16.04: Change lock screen default value

Tags: xubuntu, xfce

By default there seems to be no automatic lock screen in Xubuntu 16.04. Which file needs to be changed to get the screen locked after 10m inactivity?

I know where to change it via a GUI on a user base, but I want to change the default for all users.

Greetings, Florian

Comment: take a look at:
[xubuntu 16.04: how do I make it lock screen automatically after timeout](https://askubuntu.com/questions/818919/xubuntu-16-04-how-do-i-make-it-lock-screen-automatically-after-timeout/819152)

Answer (score 0):

One way that can do it is the `xcsreensaver`.  It has the ability to automatically lock the screen for you.

You can install `xscreensaver` by typing in from a terminal window:

```
sudo apt install xscreensaver
```

Then you can go to the settings (*Applications > Settings > Screensaver*) and set for however long you want before the automatic lock kicks in after the screen saver has started:

[image]

Hope this helps!