# How do I lock screen automatically after timeout? There is no screensaver menu!

Tags: xubuntu, lock-screen

I have read the [Anwar’s answer to a related question](https://askubuntu.com/a/819173/250300)
but cannot find the screensaver menu.

[image: Personal settings screenshot]

How to fix the problem?

Version:

```
lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 16.04.4 LTS
Release:    16.04
Codename:   xenial
```